# Could not find a primary key attribute on the model `user`. All models must contain an attribute that acts as the primary key

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, waterline

I have a waterline model as defined below,

```
var Waterline = require('Waterline');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

var User = Waterline.Collection.extend({
identity: 'user',
datastore: 'myMongo',
autoPK: false,
attributes: {
    id: {
        type: 'integer',
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    email: {
        type: 'string',
        email: true,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    username: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true,
    },

    image: {
        type: 'string'
    },

    password: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },

    mobNo: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
    aadharNo: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },

    toJSON: function () {
        var obj = this.toObject();
        delete obj.password;
        return obj;
    }
},

beforeCreate: function (values, next) {
    var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (err, salt) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        bcrypt.hash(values.password, salt, function (err, hash) {
            if (err) return next(err);

            values.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
}
});

module.exports = User;
```

While running the application, when waterline is getting initialized I'm getting following error

```
userError: Could not find a primary key attribute on the model `user`. All models must contain an attribute that acts as the primary key and is guaranteed to be unique.
at normalizeCollection (C:\Users\shriko\WebstormProjects\baclasses\node_modules\waterline-schema\lib\waterline-schema\schema.js:85:44)
at arrayEach (C:\Users\shriko\WebstormProjects\baclasses\node_modules\@sailshq\lodash\lib\index.js:1439:13)
at Function.<anonymous> (C:\Users\shriko\WebstormProjects\baclasses\node_modules\@sailshq\lodash\lib\index.js:3500:13)
at schemaBuilder (C:\Users\shriko\WebstormProjects\baclasses\node_modules\waterline-schema\lib\waterline-schema\schema.js:34:5)
at new WaterlineSchema (C:\Users\shriko\WebstormProjects\balajiclasses\node_modules\waterline-schema\lib\waterline-schema.js:36:12)
at Object.initialize (C:\Users\shriko\WebstormProjects\baclasses\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline.js:581:26)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\shriko\WebstormProjects\baclasses\bin\www:32:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

As you can see, autoPK is false, manual primary key is set, still getting this.

I'm using "waterline": "^0.13.1-9" with express.
What else is remaining to create a primary key??

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the [validation](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-schema/blob/master/lib/waterline-schema/schema.js#L84) code in the waterline-schema package reveals that the primary key has to be set in the schema definition as well.

```
var User = Waterline.Collection.extend({
identity: 'user',
datastore: 'myMongo',
autoPK: false,
primaryKey: 'id',
attributes: {
    id: {
        type: 'integer',
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    }
```

Comment: Modified my answer.The validation was not on attributes.